# Unable to save file with Telerik AsyncUpload file format is not supported

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have used this control dozens of times before. Here is my code:

```
UploadInvestment.UploadedFiles[0].SaveAs(fil, true);
```

I have debugged the code and the value of the full path that i was using to save the file is:

`"C:\\Users\\Bodokh\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\WebSites\\HakerenWeb\\uploads\\321321321\\1\\Dec 12 2014 12:00AM\\10294480_516570428449015_4669240829264786103_n.jpg"`

basically thats what fil equals to.

which seems to be in correct format... what can be the problem?

before you even suggest it, yes i used Path.Combine to combine the files instead of using plus's though i dont know how that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me...
"Dec 12 2014 12:00AM"

"12:00AM"

":"!!!

forgot to remove the ":"